# Возникновение ошибки при открытии выполняемого файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Можете объяснить почему не открывается файл openfile.py если вызывать его через main.py. При нажитии на меню file и так же нажав на кнопку открыть тест окно вызываемое сразу же уничтожается. Подскажите решение данной проблемы.

Файл main.py

```
import sys
import openfile
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
def center():
    qr = root.frameGeometry()
    cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
    qr.moveCenter(cp)
    root.move(qr.topLeft())
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
root= QWidget()    
hbox = QHBoxLayout(root)
topleft = QFrame(root)
topleft.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
topleft.resize(15,0)
topright = QFrame(root)
topright.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
splitter1 = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
splitter1.addWidget(topleft)
splitter1.resize(0,20)
splitter1.addWidget(topright)
hbox.addWidget(splitter1)
root.setLayout(hbox)
root.setFixedSize(1000,1000)
center()
root.setWindowTitle('QSplitter')
menubar = QMenuBar()
exitAction = QAction( 'Открыть тест', root)
exitAction.triggered.connect(openfile.openfilebox)
fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('File')
fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)
hbox.setMenuBar(menubar)
root.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Файл openfile.py

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
def openfilebox():
    def center():
        qr = windowsroot.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        windowsroot.move(qr.topLeft())

    def setchoise(choise):
        print(choise.text())
    windowsroot= QWidget()
    hbox = QHBoxLayout(windowsroot)
    topleft = QFrame(windowsroot)
    topleft.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
    splitter1 = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
    splitter1.addWidget(topleft)
    hbox.addWidget(splitter1)
    windowsroot.setLayout(hbox)
    choise = QListWidget(topleft)
    windowsroot.button_group = QButtonGroup()
    for b in range(30):
        choise.addItems([str(b)+'\n'])
    choise.resize(700,680)
    choise.setFont(QFont('Times', 13))
    choise.itemDoubleClicked.connect(setchoise)
    choise.show()
    windowsroot.setFixedSize(400,700)
    windowsroot.setWindowTitle('Файл')
    windowsroot.show()
```

Comment: В вопросе нет: 1) структуры проекта, 2) ошибки, что возникла у вас. UPD. У меня открылось, главное что скрипты находятся в одной папке. Но у вас есть в коде одна проблема, из-за чего окно виджета в openfilebox будет закрываться -- ссылка объекта на windowsroot после выполнения функции будет уничтожена, тут есть несколько путей и самый простой в функции открывать не виджет, а диалог. Но я бы советовал создать свой класс и с ним работать или на крайний случай сделать windowsroot глобальной

Comment: @gil9red как понять глобальным т.е. просто написать в main.py `global windowsroot` ? Я не сильно понимаю как в диалоговом окне сделать так чтобы было разделение по фреймам это как нибудь можно как пример при поднести пожалуйста. Спасибо

Comment: т.е. та переменная не должна быть локальной внутри функции, например вынести переменную на уровень модуля openfile.py. Но это крайнее, предыдущие варианты лучше, причем на порядок

Comment: @gil9red   а разве не откроется сразу 2 окна когда я буду открывать main.py? если я вынесу ее из функции

Comment: @gil9red можете привести пример на данном коде а то мне не совсем понятно как это вообще должно работать

Comment: Хорошо, будут вам все варианты, которые я предлагал )

Comment: @gil9red Спасибо добрый человек)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если делать приложение каноничным, считай, правильным способом, то это через классы и объекты, т.е. ООП.

В примере я показал как создавать собственные виджеты, как из одного окна открывать другой, как через сигналы-слоты из второго виджета посылать события в первый:

```
import traceback
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))

    print(text)
    QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Error', text)
    sys.exit()


sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions


class FileBox(QWidget):
    new_item_clicked = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('Файл')

        self.choise = QListWidget()
        self.choise.setFont(QFont('Times', 13))
        self.choise.addItems(['{}\n'.format(i) for i in range(30)])
        self.choise.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self._on_set_choise)

        top_left = QFrame()
        top_left.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)

        layout_top_left = QVBoxLayout()
        layout_top_left.addWidget(self.choise)
        top_left.setLayout(layout_top_left)

        splitter1 = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
        splitter1.addWidget(top_left)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(splitter1)
        self.setLayout(hbox)

    def _on_set_choise(self, item):
        text = item.text()
        print(text)

        self.new_item_clicked.emit(text)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('MainWindow Test')

        self.my_left_label = QLabel('<NULL>')
        self.my_left_label.setFont(QFont('Times', 13))

        self.my_right_label = QLabel('<NULL>')
        self.my_right_label.setFont(QFont('Times', 13))

        self.file_box = FileBox()
        self.file_box.setFixedSize(400, 700)
        self.file_box.choise.itemDoubleClicked.connect(lambda item: self.my_left_label.setText(item.text()))
        self.file_box.new_item_clicked.connect(lambda text: self.my_right_label.setText(text))

        top_left = QFrame()
        top_left.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)

        layout_top_left = QVBoxLayout()
        layout_top_left.addWidget(self.my_left_label)
        top_left.setLayout(layout_top_left)

        top_right = QFrame()
        top_right.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)

        layout_top_right = QVBoxLayout()
        layout_top_right.addWidget(self.my_right_label)
        top_right.setLayout(layout_top_right)

        splitter1 = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
        splitter1.addWidget(top_left)
        splitter1.addWidget(top_right)

        self.setCentralWidget(splitter1)

        menu_bar = QMenuBar()
        file_menu = menu_bar.addMenu('File')

        action_exit = file_menu.addAction('Открыть тест')
        action_exit.triggered.connect(self._on_open_file_box)

        self.setMenuBar(menu_bar)

    def _on_open_file_box(self):
        self.file_box.show()

    def center(self):
        geometry = self.frameGeometry()
        pos = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        geometry.moveCenter(pos)
        self.move(geometry.topLeft())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.resize(800, 600)
    mw.center()
    mw.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Если импортировать только нужные объекты:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QListWidget, QFrame, QVBoxLayout, QSplitter, QHBoxLayout, QMessageBox, QMainWindow, QLabel, QMenuBar, QDesktopWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
```

Либо импортировать нужны Qt модуль, и для каждого объекта, который к нему относится приписывать модуль: `QWidget` -> `QtWidgets.QWidget`

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Исправленный код из вопроса, в котором используется не виджет, а модальный диалог:
Достаточно подправить openfile.py:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

def openfilebox():
    def center():
        qr = windowsroot.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        windowsroot.move(qr.topLeft())

    def setchoise(choise):
        print(choise.text())

    windowsroot = QDialog()
    hbox = QHBoxLayout(windowsroot)
    topleft = QFrame(windowsroot)
    topleft.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
    splitter1 = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
    splitter1.addWidget(topleft)
    hbox.addWidget(splitter1)
    windowsroot.setLayout(hbox)
    choise = QListWidget(topleft)
    windowsroot.button_group = QButtonGroup()
    for b in range(30):
        choise.addItems([str(b)+'\n'])
    choise.resize(700,680)
    choise.setFont(QFont('Times', 13))
    choise.itemDoubleClicked.connect(setchoise)
    choise.show()
    windowsroot.setFixedSize(400,700)
    windowsroot.setWindowTitle('Файл')
    windowsroot.exec()
```

---

Нужно импортировать после создания QApplication, т.к. виджеты не могу существовать без QApplication, а в openfile.py виджет как раз будет создаваться при импортировании

в main.py:

```
...
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

# Сначала нужно создать QApplication
import openfile

root= QWidget()
...
```

Реализация через глобальную переменную, нужно подправить код в обоих файлах.

Вынести windowsroot из функции, сделав его глобальным (код кое-как рабочий, но так делать не нужно).

openfile.py:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

windowsroot = QWidget()

def openfilebox():
    def center():
        qr = windowsroot.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        windowsroot.move(qr.topLeft())

    def setchoise(choise):
        print(choise.text())

    hbox = QHBoxLayout(windowsroot)
    ...
```

Comment: Почему так делать не нужно? Это как то влияет на скорость?

Comment: @Дмитрий, дело в глобальный переменных. Они сами по себе неплохие, но код делают запутаннее, особенно если их значение где-то внутри меняется. С ними очень просто ошибиться. Лучше использовать локальные переменные, т.к. о них нужно думать в их области видимости.

Comment: Большое спасибо за объяснение. Этот вопрос конечно не в эту тему будет но вы не знаете как интервал сделать `Qlistwidget` а то у меня это как вывод цифры и `'\n' ` идет)

Comment: Не уверен, что понял, наверное это: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistview.html#spacing-prop Если создадите вопрос и оставите ссылку, смогу ответить с кодом и примером

Comment: да это именно то спасибо еще раз)

Comment: @Дмитрий что бы понять почему так делать нельзя, почитайте про ООП, реюзабельность кода, точно так=же как его чистота и восприятие.     Накатав простыню размеров в 5к строк, вы начнете терятса что и где у вас и зачем.

К примеру  пример вашего когда полностью не читаем и желания копатса в нем нет, однако в ответе код для вас отформатировали вполне коректно и я его даже просмотрел бегло.

Comment: @gil9red все хорошо, только импорт через * это зло, страшное. за него сажать надо

Comment: @Reishin, ну да, зато удобно -- не нужно думать какие объекты из модулей Qt нужно заранее импортировать, либо при написании кода на это отвлекаться. Никто не помешает после написания кода вместо * перечислить что было использовано

Comment: @Reishin, если по производительности, то импортирование всего, конечно, больше выполняется, но тут вопрос производительности может быть просто смешной. Выполнил я несколько замеров времени импортирования и вывел среднее значение: `0.03255029262149497` при импортировании всего и `0.03142194606877782` при импортировании только нужных объектов. Поэтому считаю, что не нужно сильно беспокоиться насчет импорта всего

Comment: @gil9red нет, вопрос не в производительности. прошу ознакомтесь тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad

Comment: @Reishin, ну и как много классов с префиксом Q вы видели и в своем коде используете? Оо Да и в целом если это плохо, то почему этот импорт еще не убрали? И тому вопросу уже больше 10 лет, за это время могло много чего измениться. И я включу в ответ импорт с указанными объектами

Comment: @gil9red нет, за много лет ничего особого не поменялось. Вопрос не в том, сколько я использую; ответ же вы пишете не для себя  и говорить о том какие библиотеки еще использует %username% не можете?